Python - Как обратиться к классу ниже
Есть такой код
class A:
    abc: B
...

class B:
...

суть в том что я хочу создать подсказку указав что поле будет иметь класс B. Но VS Code говорит мне что B не определен. Да и не запускается такой код. В С++ для решения этой проблемы можно было бы просто перед class A написать что то вроде class B. Но в Python так не получается.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344418/4928642

from __future__ import annotations

tio.run
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
  abc: B

class B:
  pass


А если эти классы находятся в разных модулях и модуль с классом B включает модуль с классом A?

@ArtemiiSelyankin, так это же просто строки - по идее, никакой разницы?

или я что то не так понял или разница все же есть. Если я пишу from __future__ import annotations то это работает только в области одного модуля. А все что в других модулях игнорится.

@ArtemiiSelyankin, ну надо писать в том модуле, где ты используешь аннотации. Я подробнее не знаю. Если не помогло, посмотри полный ответ на английском или убери галочку и подожди, пока кто-то ещё ответит. Я больше не знаю.

@ArtemiiSelyankin если классы находятся в разных модулях, то у вас не будет проблем с порядком классов, но может быть проблема циклического импорта из-за аннотаций, тогда см. тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1591458/1365
